# Netlogo: seting a global variable to a single patch

Tags: variables, netlogo

I'm trying to set a global variable to be a single patch that has the machine-type "riveter". The global variabe is active-patch. There is only one patch with that machine-type in the world. The machine-type is a patches-own variable.

```
  set active-patch one-of patches [machine-type = "riveter"]
```

I've tried this but it expects a command inside the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing the `with`

```
set active-patch one-of patches with [machine-type = "riveter"]
```